# XSL Fo - No Page Break in element

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a problem with the FO flow, because on one page the title shows up in the end of one page and continues on the page after. How can I add an attribute to the title-element so the title is always displayed on the same page, that means: NO page break.

Thanks!

/Dannie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `keep-together.within-page="always"` to the `fo:block` that contains your title.

Example:

```
<fo:block keep-together.within-page="always">Your title...</fo:block>
```